# Kafka python client consumer behaviour in case of 1 consumer and multiple partitions

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, producer-consumer

I have a topic with 100 partitions and a single application running to consume messages from this topic. Since there is only 1 consumer, all 100 partitions would get assigned to this particular consumer. I wanted to understand what would happen in the case when all partitions have messages that need to be consumed.

1. Would it go in order? i.e First consume all messages from partition #1 then move to partition #2 and so on...
2. Would it consume in a round-robin fashion? i.e First consume 1 message from partition #1 then move to partition #2 and so on after consuming 1 message from all partitions come back to partition #1?

I have observed the #1 but I want a behaviour where which is more like #2, can that be achieved any way?

Comment: You can assign your consumer to specific partitions rather than let it default to read all. Once you detect the "end" of a partition, you can reassign the consumer to the next

Comment: Interesting, would you suggest to first fetch all available partitions and then select a partition and read message? What would happen in case of partition reassignment? To implement this, consumer loop should also contain a fetch_partitions `assignment()` method to ensure partition rebalancing is also taken care of. I will try to implement this and report my findings! Thanks

Comment: Rebalancing wouldn't change the number of partitions in the topic, so calling assign method of consumer instance with the same partition should be fine, but yes, querying for the total partition count makes sense, however you said you know it is already 100

Answer (score 0):

Configure `max.poll.records=1`  in Configuration.
This will poll Single kafka message in one consumer call.

Comment: This doesn't guarantee any order of the partitions  though

Comment: Yep, I tried this already. Behaviour is same as #1.

Comment: Alternative , assigning manual assignment of partition should work. So your consumer have more granual control than auto assignment by kafka.  i can see this has been suggested in comment.  One more suggestion, why to built 1:100 ratio, can you change the number of partitions to 1 or some lesser number?

Comment: Yep, seems like manual partition assignment looks like the only option. 1:100 is the peak ratio, ideally it would be something between 1:10-1:20